# Access violation when opening OpenCV VideoCapture (release only)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, visual-studio-2013, access-violation

I have an application written in visual studio, utilizing OpenCV 2.4.10.  The program executes flawlessly in debug mode, but in release mode it crashes on the first command following a VideoCapture::open() call, regardless of whether the call was completed in the constructor or with the method call.  I recognize that this is a pretty common occurrence, and that a dll linkage may be the issue, but have been unable to fully identify the problem.  Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Here is the error message:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x03DE7D43 (opencv_ffmpeg2410.dll) in OpenCVLaserDot.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
```

Here is the segment of code surrounding the VideoCapture instantiation:

```
const string DEFAULT_INPUT_FILE = "C:/Users/Tyler/Documents/Visual Studio 2013/Projects/OpenCVLaserDot/Release/a.avi";

VideoCapture cap; 
if (inputFile == "1" || inputFile == ""){
    cap.open(DEFAULT_INPUT_FILE);
} else {
    cap.open(inputFile);
}
if (!cap.isOpened()){ 
    printf("Failed to open video\n");
    return -1; 
}
```

Comment: Are you linking the same libs in debug and release ( apart from *d.lib)? Do you link to vfw32.lib?

Comment: The same libs are linked in debug and release, with the debug only containing the *d.lib and the release containing all *.lib files (it crashes on launch if I don't do that).  vfw32.lib is not in my list though, and is not in my opencv directory.  Where can I find that file?

Comment: just add it, is already in the path. I don't know if it'll solve the problem, but give it a try

Comment: I added it.  It had no affect on the program execution.  The problem persists.